# Derivation of Wave equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Is there a reference you know of that derives the (dimension $> 1$) wave equation starting from the Navier-Stokes equations?

Comment: Any particular "wave equation"? Navier-Stokes admits various exact and approximate wave-like solutions but is not equivalent to a wave equation alone (because it's dissipative).

Comment: @Sharkos For example, on the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation, they derive the 1d wave equation from Hooke's law.  I was told the (3d) wave eq in that form can be derived from Navier-Stokes.

Comment: I think you're a little confused. The analogous thing to Hooke $\rightarrow$ wave equation is a derivation **of** Navier-Stokes.

Comment: @Sharkos Maybe.. They have a derivation here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave_equation but it's just in 1 d

Comment: That's not a derivation of the wave equation, that's a solution of the wave equation. Wave equations, such as the acoustic one there, can be derived as approximations to Navier-Stokes.

Comment: @Sharkos How is it not a derivation? 
Derivation of the acoustic wave equation

"The wave equation can be developed from the linearized one-dimensional continuity equation, the linearized one-dimensional force equation and the equation of state."

Comment: Apologies, I'm viewing on mobile browsers and missed that subsection. Nonetheless I reiterate there are only various approximate wave equations. For example, in that derivation we start "neglecting small terms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not usre what you mean exactly. But in fluid dynamics community, they have two routes as follows:

$$
\text{Hyperbolic conservation law}
\\
\downarrow \qquad\qquad \qquad  \downarrow
\\
\text{3D Navier-Stokes Equation} 
\quad \hspace{1.2in}  
\\ \swarrow\hspace{1.2in} \downarrow
\\
\text{2D Shallow Water Equation} \hspace{1in}\text{1D Boussinesq Approximation}$$

For NSE to SWE, Google gives me [these nice slides](http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~arbogast/cam397/dawson_v2.pdf) , I read through it briefly, it triggered my old memory of taking fluid dynamics class pretty nicely. Basically, you follow the route: density is assumed to be a constant (slide 18) and pressure is decoupled (slide 17), depth is integrated out (slide 19).

The 1D water wave, [Boussinesq approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_%28water_waves%29), which is a wave-like equation:
$$
u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + u_{xxxx} + \epsilon (u^2)_{xx}.
$$